# make splite progress bar with filling inside every element

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to make splite progress bar with percentage  fill inside every element. 1 step = 1%. Example on image and also attach an example css cod.
I guess I need just right way for filling every element, i have idea to add much elements with progress bar inside, but it's stupid way

```css
.progress-bar {
    margin-right: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.progress{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 474px;
}

.progress-bar-success{
    background-color: #0099FF;
}

.progress-bar-danger{
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 80%;
    border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 12.5%"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 12.5%"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 12.5%"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 12.5%"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 12.5%"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 12.5%"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 12.5%"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 12.5%"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 12.5%"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You could have it done with ranges. Like the first box is progress from 0 to 10%, then 10 to 20% etc. I'm removing both React and Vue tags btw.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `linear-gradient()`:

```css
.progress-bar {
    margin-right: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.progress{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 474px;
}

.progress-bar-success{
    background-color: #0099FF;
}

.progress-bar-danger{
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 80%;
    border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 12.5%"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 12.5%; background: linear-gradient(to right ,#5cb85c , #5cb85c 30%, transparent 30%);">
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 12.5%"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 12.5%"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 12.5%"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 12.5%"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 12.5%"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 12.5%"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 12.5%"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```